# how to get DOMDocument when compiling PHP7.4 from source?

Tags: php, compilation, domdocument, php-7.4

how do you get DOMDocument when compiling php7.4 from source? i'm on Amazon Linux 2 and compiling php7.4 like this:

```
yum install autoconf bison re2c libxml2 gcc && \
rm -rf php-src && \
git clone -b 'PHP-7.4' --depth 1 https://github.com/php/php-src.git && \
cd 'php-src' && \
./buildconf && \
./configure --disable-all --disable-cgi --enable-cli --with-curl --with-libxml && \
make clean && \
make -j $(nproc) && \
rm -rfv ../php && \
cp -v ./sapi/cli/php ../php
```

and to my amazement, the resuling php-cli binary does not have DOMDocument available:

```
[root@ip-192-168-84-98 php]# ./php test.php 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /hans_temp/php/test.php:558
Stack trace:
#0 /hans_temp/php/test.php(573): get_gps_coordiates_from_finn_id('237587045')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /hans_temp/php/test.php on line 558
```

i thought --with-libxml was supposed to add DOMDocument, but here it doesn't... i can theorize that there is a bug between the flags `--disable-all` and `--with-libxml` -or- that i'm missing something for DOMDocument support, help? (fwiw the `--with-curl` works great, adding the curl_* api)

config.log: https://termbin.com/18i8 (too big to inline on stackoverflow.com )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when compiling with --disable-all, you need both `--with-libxml` *and*  `--enable-dom` for DOMDocument to be available.

```
./configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-libxml --enable-dom
```